# Different CSS file when in development mode

Tags: 8

Using Gulp I create two css files. One style.css and one style.min.css. Is it possible to load the style.css when developing (locally) and the style.min.css when in production (remote)?

Comment: Try reading about the config split: [Creating a simple split configuration: Dev modules only in dev environments](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/configuration-split/creating-a-simple-split-configuration-dev-modules-only-in-dev). This may also be relevant: [Creating advanced theme settings](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/creating-advanced-theme-settings).

Comment: If you use the Advanced Aggregates module you can have all the CSS and JS you use minimised and aggregated automatically. https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/advanced-cssjs-aggregation/advanced-aggregates

Comment: It's possible yes. You can check for environment variables or base URL or use config split to enable different modules per environment to attach different libraries. For all 3 mentioned approaches you can use `hook_page_attachments`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify two different libraries in mymodule.libraries.yml. Then in your mymodule.module file attach the one that matches your current deployment env:

```
function mymodule_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {
  if (PRODUCTION) {
    $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'mymodule/lib_prod';
  } else {
    $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'mymodule/lib_dev';
  }
}
```

I am using code like this to decide on which deployment level I am:

```
  public static function getDeploymentStage() : string {
    // lazy cache
    static $ds = null;

    if (null == $ds) {
      if (isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])) {
        switch ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) {
          case 'anwalt-seiten.de':
          case 'www.anwalt-seiten.de':
            $ds = AsdentBaseService::DS_PROD;
            break;
          case 'stage.anwalt-seiten.de':
            $ds = AsdentBaseService::DS_STAGE;
            break;
          default:
            $ds = AsdentBaseService::DS_DEVELOPMENT;
            break;
        }
      } else {
        $ds = AsdentBaseService::DS_DEVELOPMENT;
      }
    }

    return $ds;
  }
```

Note that any drush command will run in dev-mode here.
You can also use $settings from settings.php or any environment variable instead.

Comment: `if (getenv('MYENVFOOBAR') === 'production')` ...

Comment: Thanks it works. I used the base URL to check if its in running local or remote. Does this have any negative effect on the performance? Do the files get loaded later because of the hook or the way I'm figuring out it is local or remote?

Comment: Don't think there's any impact on performance (use caching!) - and also there's no change in processing order by calling that hook.

Comment: One more question, I noticed when using this. The attached css also overwrites styling on my admin pages. Is there a way to have this only work on none admin pages?

Comment: Use another theme for admin at the bottom of /admin/appearance

Comment: Another approach is to check for the current user in the mymodule_page_attachments() decision. But then you need to add "user" to the cache context of each page.